# Little League pitching rule clarification please

Tags: rules, baseball

We are a Minor's Division team (9 & 10 year olds).

I wanted to rotate between my two pitchers by inning. I pitched my first kid for an inning, switched kids and pitched the second one for an inning. On the third inning I tried to have my first kid pitch again, but the other team manager said that was against the rules.

The rule states (regulation VI, part B):
**A pitcher once removed from the mound cannot return as a pitcher.**

Did I 'remove the pitcher from the mound' when I tried to rotate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Removing a pitcher from the mound is any action where the pitcher *was* the pitcher, and is now *no longer* the pitcher.

It's worth noting that this is a place (among many), where Little League departs from MLB rules. In MLB rules you can take a pitcher off the mound, make him a field player, and then bring him back to the mound. However, because Little League has free substition, this could (and would) cause managers to abuse pitching changes in a way that isn't keeping with the spirit of the game.

So yes, once a kid has pitched in a little league game, they can't pitch again in that same game, even if they stay out.